# Canvas image drawing is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to draw image using canvas after window loading in Javascript but I could get only a part of an image I could not get the full image.please help me.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <script>

        window.onload = function() {
            drawEx1();
        }

        var image1 = null;

        function drawEx1() {
            image1 = new Image();
            image1.src =
                "file:///C:/Users/Documents/project%20trails/app/i.jpg";
            image1.addEventListener('load', drawImage1);
        }

        function drawImage1() {
            var canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas1");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            context.drawImage(image1, 10, 10);
        }

            </script>

        </head>
        <body >
            <div >

               <input type="button" id="btn" value="submit" />
                <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `drawImage1` function to the following. Run the code snippet below to see in action.

```
    function drawImage1() {
        var canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = 400;
        canvas.height = 400;
        context.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, image1.width, image1.height, 0, 0, 400, 300);
    }
```

```html
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    drawEx1();
  }

  var image1 = null;

  function drawEx1() {
    image1 = new Image();
    image1.src =
      "http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/003/556/940/edab30087cea36c0ca206fc61a4b10fa_crop_north.jpg?w=630&h=420&q=75";
    image1.addEventListener('load', drawImage1);
  }

  function drawImage1() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 300;
    context.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, image1.width, image1.height, 0, 0, 400, 300);
  }
</script>


<body>
  <div>

    <input type="button" id="btn" value="submit" />
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ...or `canvas.width=image1.width+10` and `canvas.height=image1.height+10` followed by `context.drawImage(image1,10,10)`

Comment: but i could not real size as the original image.how to get the original image size

Comment: @ArvindA You say you are getting only getting part of your image to show. Paul is making a good suggestion that your canvas might be too small to fit the entire image. You use image1.width & image1.height to get the full (original) size of your image ... then set the canvas width at least as large as the original size.

Comment: its working thanks markE ,paul alot.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing your onload listener until after the source has been set, this likely means the onload event never fires

```
    window.onload = function() {
        drawEx1();
    }

    var image1 = null;

    function drawEx1() {
        image1 = new Image();
        image1.addEventListener('load', drawImage1);
        image1.src =
            "file:///C:/Users/Documents/project%20trails/app/i.jpg";

    }

    function drawImage1() {
        var canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        // resize the image as needed
        context.drawImage(image1, 10, 10); // include desired image size and image width on this line
    }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body >
        <div >

           <input type="button" id="btn" value="submit" />
            <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I would also try running the solution is a webserver (IIS express, apache) and loading the image via URL and not file path.  I think in this case you should be able to load image via file path, but it may cause issues when trying to modify that element

Comment: Hi. By habit I too set onload before setting the src, but since even local images take a few ms to load it is unlikely that the onload will be skipped. Also, here, since the OP put both src and onload in a function the onload might be hoisted during preflight -- I'm not sure. BTW, I didn't downvote you.

Comment: onload will no be hoisted in this scenario (ttbomk).  I have seen that exact code fail many times for that exact reason.  Oh well, what I get for trying to help ppl.

Comment: @markE, "but since even local images take a few ms to load it is unlikely that the onload will be skipped.". Cache takes less than a few ms... webkit browsers won't stack the event to the process flow, but fire it immediately. Good habit you have, good advice by OP.

Comment: @Kaiido. Fair enough. My "habit" might be a "requirement" :-0